# Inner component not found when retargetMethodExpressions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have to write a composite component that shows a login form and can be used with the following code snippet:

```
<login:loginForm username="#{loginBean.username}" 
                 password="#{loginBean.password}" 
                 action="#{loginBean.login}"/>
```

My loginBean is just a simple serializable `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` with getters, setters and a `public String login()` method.

This is my composite component:

```
<body>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="username" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
        <cc:attribute name="password" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
        <cc:attribute name="action" targets="submit" required="true" method-signature="java.lang.String f()"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <h3><span xml:lang="en">Login</span> Daten </h3>
        <h:form>
            <div class="formblock">
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Username" for="username"/>
                        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{cc.attrs.username}"/>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Passwort" for="password"/>
                        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{cc.attrs.password}"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Anmelden" accesskey="r" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </cc:implementation>
</body>
```

But, when I open the login.xhtml page (which contains the `login:loginForm`-snippet) in the browser, I can see the following Error in the jetty log:

```
Apr 29, 2012 11:59:49 PM org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage retargetMethodExpressions
SEVERE: Inner component submit not found when retargetMethodExpress
```

**But what does that mean? Where is the mistake in my code?** I already tried some other solutions for implementing the `action` attribute, but without success.

Comment: Just saw that I used myfaces version 2.0.4 instead of the current 2.1.7 release. So, upgraded and now the error is gone. But the action still is not executed when clicking the command button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After upgrading to myfaces version 2.1.7 the straigt-forward solution without the `target`-stuff works:

```
<body>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="username" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
        <cc:attribute name="password" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
        <cc:attribute name="action" required="true" method-signature="java.lang.String f()"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <h3><span xml:lang="en">Login</span> Daten </h3>
        <h:form>
            <div class="formblock">
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Username" for="username"/>
                        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{cc.attrs.username}"/>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Passwort" for="password"/>
                        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{cc.attrs.password}"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <h:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.action}" value="Anmelden" accesskey="r" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </cc:implementation>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The target="submit" is incorrect, because h:form is NamingContainer, so you need to assign and id to that component and change target to "myForm:submit" or something like that.

Comment: You mean I should replace `targets="submit"` with `targets="myForm:submit"` and `<h:form>` with `<h:form id="myForm">` and then it should work?